# How can I ensure Android buttons have the same height when they are in different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, view, height, android-relativelayout

I have a view containing two `Button`s and a `TextView`. They are layer out, using a `RelativeLayout` as shown below:

```
                  +-----------+
__TextView___     | Button 1  |
                  +-----------+
+-----------+
| Button 2  |
+-----------+
```

The key here is that TextView and Button 1 have identical heights, enforced by `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` on Button 1

Button 2 is constrained to have the same width as TextView (using `layout_alignLeft` and `layout_alignRight`).

The problem is that I also want it to have the same height as Button 1 using something like:

```
layout_height="@id/button_1"
```

Can I achieve this entirely through the use of Layouts ?

If not, is there some code I could deploy in the Activity that uses the view to force this *post* layout but before display ?

I'd really like to avoid having to create a special `View` to achieve this.

In iOS land I can specific that various controls have the same height or width but I can't see a way to do this in Android.

Comment: if you use android:layout_height="wrap_content" and android:textSize=10sp or same font size for both the buttons i guess you can have same height for your buttons

Comment: @MaulikSheth This is true but I want to avoid explicitly setting the size and I want the size to be related to the input EditText

Comment: Use device independent pixels (dips) for your measurement. The system will ensure same size on different devices and densities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put this in your activity onCreate method

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button2.getLayoutParams();
        int height = button1.getHeight();
        btParams.height = height;
        button2.setLayoutParams(btParams);
    }
});
```